# Can I refill my saltshaker on Mars?

Tags: geology

I guess we will need to take our lunch to Mars for some time before we are able to produce food there! But do we need to take a saltshaker too?

Can we extract editable salt from the crust of Mars, Moon, Titan or Europa?

Comment: If your question is about extraction of one salt from a mixture of salts, it's not about Astronomy. If you'd like to ask how much sodium and chloride are in salts found on these bodies, that would be on-topic.

Comment: The principle elemental abundance is not that different, the actual chemistry is. so you likely will have to crack Regolith and create you salt from that

Comment: The question seems a more appropriate fit to https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @B--rian Indeed, there's both a salt on Mars and a rust on the Moon question there: [Which “exotic salt” can lower water's freezing point by 70 °C?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/114837/16035) and [Why and how is rust forming on moon?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/139987/16035)